# Convert FSM to NuSMV model

Tags: fsm, model-checking, nusmv

i hame fsm like this FSM

[image: my FSM]

and i wrote piece of code to check LTL property on FSM
this is my LTL property

```
G!(r1 & r2) -> (G(!g1 | !g2) & G(r1 -> F(g1)) & G(r2 -> F(g2)))
```

my NuSMV code is

```
MODULE main
VAR
    state : 0 .. 2;
    r1 : boolean;
    r2 : boolean;
    g1 : boolean;
    g2 : boolean;
ASSIGN
    init (state) := 0;
    init(r1) := FALSE;
    init(r2) := FALSE;
    init(g1) := FALSE;
    init(g2) := FALSE;
    next(state) :=
        case
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : 1;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (r2) & (g2)  : 0;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : 0;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (r2) & (g2)  : 0;
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : 0;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (!r2) & (g2)  : 1;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : 1;
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : 1;
            TRUE : state;
        esac;
    next(g1) :=
        case
            (state = 1) & (!r1) & (r2) & (g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (!r1) & (!r2) & (g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (r1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (r1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (r1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!r1) & (r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : g1;
        esac;
    next(r1) :=
        case
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : r1;
        esac;
    next(r2) :=
        case
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : {TRUE, FALSE};
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (g2)  : {TRUE, FALSE};
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : r2;
        esac;
    next(g2) :=
        case
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r1) & (r2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (!r2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (!r2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (!r2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (r2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (r1) & (!r2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (r2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (r2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : g2;
        esac;
```

After model checking with following command i wonder when i see NuSMV return True

```
NuSMV -int
read_model -i test2.smv
flatten_hierarchy
encode_variables
build_model
pick_state -i

check_ltlspec -p "G!(r1 & r2) -> (G(!g1 | !g2) & G(r1 -> F(g1)) & G(r2 -> F(g2)))"
```

NuSMV result is :

```
-- specification ( G !(r1 & r2) -> (( G (!g1 | !g2) &  G (r1 ->  F g1)) &  G (r2 ->  F g2)))  is true
```

but i can find CE manually
after read NuSMV 2.6  User Manual i could not find which part of NuSMV code is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found problem 
something goes wrong in my model 
in this piece of code inputs modelled but it's not necessary because we just model system not environment

```
next(r1) :=
        case
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r2) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r2) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r2) & (g2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : r1;
        esac;
    next(r2) :=
        case
            (state = 0) & (g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : {TRUE, FALSE};
            (state = 1) & (!g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (!r1) & (g2)  : {TRUE, FALSE};
            (state = 1) & (g1) & (r1) & (!g2)  : TRUE;
            (state = 0) & (!g1) & (!r1) & (!g2)  : FALSE;
            TRUE : r2;
        esac;
```